# Can I declare a single variable array that can retain all student names instead of declaring so many variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where I want to assign 5 country names to variables and, in general practice, I declare five variables for all five variables that I have allocated to each country name one by one, below is the code.

```
Sub Array_Example()

  Dim India As String
  Dim Australia As String
  Dim Singapore As String
  Dim Russia As String
  Dim Malaysia As String

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use 2D arrays for this. `Dim Names(1 to 5, 1 to 100) as Variant` is you have 100 names for each of the Country

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to declare an array and then assign to that array?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Array_Example()

    Dim India As String
    Dim Australia As String
    Dim Singapore As String
    Dim Russia As String
    Dim Malaysia As String

    'versus (instead...)
    Dim students(0 To 4) As String
    students(0) = "India" 'etc

End Sub
```

Taking note of @Mikku's point re 2D arrays (in case there is an associated value):

```
Sub Array_Example()
    '2D example
    Dim students(0 To 4, 0 To 1) As String
    students(0, 0) = "India": students(0, 1) = "India's associated value"

    Stop 'Delete me later
End Sub
```

If you were going down that route (key, value) then a dict would be more useful

```
Sub Dict_Example()
    Dim students As Object

    Set students = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    students.Add "India", "India's associated value" 'etc

    Stop 'Delete me later
End Sub
```